# Log4net not writing / creating log file Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, log4net

I created a program where it should write logs to a file, but it doesn't create a log file if I try to use `log4net.config` file. But when I place the config inside `app.config`, it's working properly.

This is a Windows Forms application written using C#.

Is there anything that I missed? Please advice - thanks. Program is running properly but it won't create the log files.

My class:

```
public class Housekeeping
{
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
       (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public void WriteLog()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Writing to \"log.txt\" in the same directory as the .exe file.\n");
            log.Info("Info logging");

            try
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
                log.Error("This is my error", e);
                log.Error(DateTime.Now.ToString(), e);
            }
        }
}
```

`log4net.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs\%date{MMddHH}\%property{LogName}.log" />

      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger > %method > %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="log.txt" />

      <!--<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs\%date{MMddHH}\%property{LogName}" />-->
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="_yyyyMMdd HH'.log'"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="1" />
      <maximumFileSize value="2KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Main form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Log4NetHK;
using System.Configuration;
using log4net.Config;

namespace LogHousekeeping
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Form1));

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Log4NetHK.Housekeeping hk = new Housekeeping();

            //Thread tobj1 = new Thread(hk.TestWrite);
            Thread tobj2 = new Thread(hk.WriteLog);

            tobj2.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Disregarding any other possible issue, have you set your Config file to copy to output directory?

Comment: yes it worked form some time , but it went back to the same error